# JSON jq grouping and average

Tags: json, group-by, statistics, jq

Looking to try to group and average the following json

```
{
    "SpotPriceHistory": [
        {
        "AvailabilityZone": "ap-southeast-1c",
        "InstanceType": "t4g.small",
        "ProductDescription": "Linux/UNIX",
        "SpotPrice": "0.001200",
        "Timestamp": "2021-03-17T18:27:08+00:00"
        },
        {
        "AvailabilityZone": "ap-southeast-1a",
        "InstanceType": "t4g.small",
        "ProductDescription": "Linux/UNIX",
        "SpotPrice": "0.002400",
        "Timestamp": "2021-03-17T18:27:08+00:00"
        },
        {
        "AvailabilityZone": "ap-southeast-1b",
        "InstanceType": "t4g.small",
        "ProductDescription": "Linux/UNIX",
        "SpotPrice": "0.005600",
        "Timestamp": "2021-03-17T18:27:08+00:00"
        },
        {
        "AvailabilityZone": "ap-southeast-1a",
        "InstanceType": "m1.large",
        "ProductDescription": "Linux/UNIX",
        "SpotPrice": "0.033300",
        "Timestamp": "2021-03-17T18:20:33+00:00"
        },
        {
        "AvailabilityZone": "ap-southeast-1b",
        "InstanceType": "m1.large",
        "ProductDescription": "Linux/UNIX",
        "SpotPrice": "0.023300",
        "Timestamp": "2021-03-17T18:20:33+00:00"
        },
        {
        "AvailabilityZone": "ap-southeast-1b",
        "InstanceType": "r5ad.24xlarge",
        "ProductDescription": "Linux/UNIX",
        "SpotPrice": "1.644400",
        "Timestamp": "2021-03-17T18:20:20+00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Looking for the output to look something like,

```
{
    "AvailabilityZone": "ap-southeast",
    "InstanceType": "t4g.small",
    "ProductDescription": "Linux/UNIX",
    "SpotPrice": "0.00306"
},
{
    "AvailabilityZone": "ap-southeast",
    "InstanceType": "m1.large",
    "ProductDescription": "Linux/UNIX",
    "SpotPrice": "0.0283"
},
{
    "AvailabilityZone": "ap-southeast",
    "InstanceType": "r5ad.24xlarge",
    "ProductDescription": "Linux/UNIX",
    "SpotPrice": "1.644400"
}
```

I've got something like `.SpotPriceHistory | group_by(.InstanceType)[]` to group.

Comment: So you're trying to get all the objects where `AvailabilityZone` equals `ap-southeast`?

Comment: There are multiple `"AvailabilityZone"` per `InstanceType`?

Comment: I'm trying to group based on InstanceType and get an average price across all AvailabilityZone

Comment: Yes there are different AvailabilityZone for each InstanceType

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite sure this is not the most 'clean' solution, but thought I'd share it until there's a better approach

Idea:

1. `group_by` each `InstanceType`
2. `map` each `SpotPrice`, add those values by using `add`, devide by `map` `length` to get avarage
   `(map(.SpotPrice | tonumber) | add / length)`

```
.SpotPriceHistory | group_by(.InstanceType)[] | { "InstanceType": .[0].InstanceType, "SpotPrice": (map(.SpotPrice | tonumber) | add / length) }
```

Result:

```json
{
  "InstanceType": "m1.large",
  "SpotPrice": 0.028300000000000002
}
{
  "InstanceType": "r5ad.24xlarge",
  "SpotPrice": 1.6444
}
{
  "InstanceType": "t4g.small",
  "SpotPrice": 0.0030666666666666668
}
```

[Jq▷Play](https://jqplay.org/s/C2JY9zH9hY)